# column grouping show duplicate rows ssrs

Tags: group-by, ssrs-2008

My data set shows two rows for Item 1:

First row: Item 1 with quantity 5 for year 2014

Second row: Item 1 with quantity 10 for year 2015.

For the purpose of my SSRS report, I want the report to show Item 1 in just one row with column grouping.

How ever when I apply Column grouping on year I still get two rows.

My perception is that When I apply column grouping the report should return one row for item 1, with different quantities under column 2014 and 2015.

Can please any one help why it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a matrix, instead of table. No grouping needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually it was matrix, yet not working. I has hard time figuring out what is wrong and I could not find an answer. I ended up deleting and creating the whole matrix again and this time it is working!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you should either use Matrix instead of table or you should return your data in different format (with Quantities for Year 2014/15 in different Columns).

From msdn:

Table   **Define nested row groups, adjacent row groups, and recursive hierarchy row groups** (such as for an organizational chart). By default, a table includes a details group. Add groups by dragging dataset fields to the Grouping pane for a selected table.

Matrix   **Define nested row and *column* groups, and adjacent row and *column* groups.** Add groups by dragging dataset fields to the Grouping pane for a selected matrix.

You can find more about matrices here : [SSRS Matrices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually it was matrix, yet not working. I has hard time figuring out what is wrong and I could not find an answer. I ended up deleting and creating the whole matrix again and this time it is working!